# How to insert CSV file properly in the SQL?

Tags: mysql, csv

I am using MySQL 5.5 to import csv file into my database, I can insert the data from csv file, but some error has came out.

I using the SQL query to import my csv file:

```html
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/test_kod_sekatan_4.csv'
INTO TABLE user_access_file_test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

And my input data will get more 1 extra 0 value:

[image: Error 2]

The error message like below the picture:

[image: Error 1]

This is my database structure:

[image: db structure]

Below is my csv format

[image: CSV format]

[image: csv]

Hope someone can guide me which part I was getting wrong. Thanks.

Comment: is there a new-line too many at the end of your csv file?

Comment: May I know how to check it?

Comment: *Below is my csv format* This is NOT csv, this is its interpretation made by Excel or similar.

Comment: @Akina I have updated my question for csv format

Comment: Add the same for the rest of CSV (3-5 lines enough, 33 is excess).

Comment: as you can see in your edited question: there is an empty line (no. 33) at the end of your file

Comment: Anycase your CSV is wrong - empty space for non-specified integer is wrong (must be zero or \n). If do not want to receive warnings the use LOAD DATA ... SET syntax and parse the line programmatically.

Comment: Can you show me how to parse the line programmatically

Comment: how is this CSV created? Could you use TRIM() when creating of just before reading it?

Comment: I try your method. Thanks.